# Cannot setup Angular 2 tour of heroes tutorial

Tags: angular

Being in the page the Hero Editor (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) I follow the direction:

“Follow the setup instructions for creating a new project named angular-tour-of-heroes after which the file structure should look like this:”
However, the setup link goes to the page QuickStart live-coding example (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html#!#develop-locally) that is for installing the QuickStart  Application

So I do not get directions for the Heroes tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) repository, Install npm packages by `npm install` and follow the steps from [keep the app transpiling and running](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html#!#keep-the-app-transpiling-and-running)

Comment: There is the tutorial direction: Follow the setup instructions for creating a new project named angular-tour-of-heroes after which the file structure should look like this".  This direction misses renaming the project directory from quickstart to angular-tour-of-heroes

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
npm start
```

OR DOWNLOAD FROM https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip

Comment: I understand, quickstart works fine but how to setup the Heroes tutorial?

Comment: I was confused by the fact that these are the quickstart instructions as well but I think the idea is that you start with quickstart, which is essentially an empty "Hello, World" style app and start making the tutorial changes from there.